# Add the free trial option to the product on WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to offer a trial for each product if customer wants.
Meaning they pay only shipping fee and have a some days trial period and then rebill them on after the trial ends.
I want to do this without using plugin.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: "Is there any way to accomplish this" yes. But seriously, how can we answer this question as it is currently written?

Comment: would you explain more details please? I can`t understand what you mean